# Pasar dato de gridview (formulario hijo) a textbox formulario padre

Tags: c#

Hola buenos dias a todos, tengo el siguiente problema: en FORM_A tengo un boton desde donde llamo a FORM_B, que tiene un datagridview.

Necesito que al hacer dobleclick en una fila del datagridview en FORM_B se pasen esos valores a los textbox de FORM_A, pero no hace nada el codigo que tengo. Este codigo tengo en la grilla:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        frmMedicamentosPaciente frm = new frmMedicamentosPaciente();
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        //txtIdMedicamento.Text = row.Cells["idMedicamento"].Value.ToString();  
        //frm1.txtIdMedicamento.Text = row.Cells["idMedicamento"].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtIdMedicamento.Text = row.Cells["idMedicamento"].Value.ToString(); 
    }
```

y en FORM_A tengo los textbox como publicos

Saludos a todos y gracias desde ya

Comment: No es que no hace nada.. lo hace, pero no sobre el form que llamo.. si no sobre uno nuevo...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu problema se basa en lo siguiente:

- Form A llama a Form B
- Form B hace cosas. Form B necesita pasarle cosas a Form A.
- Form B necesita saber quien es Form A.
- Tu codigo no le dice quien es Form A, si no que **instancia** una nueva version de Form A `frmMedicamentosPaciente frm = new frmMedicamentosPaciente();`

Por que pasa esto? No estas entendiendo la diferencia entre una clase y una instancia de un objeto. Una clase es la definición de la clase, una instancia de una clase vive donde fue instanciada, y salvo que tenga propiedades estaticas, una intancia no ve los datos de otra instancia.

Al hacer `frmMedicamentosPaciente frm = new frmMedicamentosPaciente();` Estas levantando otra instancia de tu clase frmMedicamentosPaciente (Si, los forms son clases).

En realidad, formas de solucionar esto hay montones, pero una simple seria contarle a Form B, quien es form A. Para ello, en form B, define lo siguiente:

```
public frmMedicamentosPaciente frmPadre;
```

Y luego de intanciar Form B y antes de abrirlo, hace algo asi:

```
FormB.frmPadre = this;
```