# ¿Como Abrir from2 desde el form1 con animacion y despues volver del form2 al form1? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, .net

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un formulario en el cual quiero que al presionar un Button se abra el formulario 2 (con una animación la cual hice con un timer) y desde el formulario 2 al presionar un Button que vuelva al form1 con la misma animación del timer... (Espero y me explique bien)

el codigo del form1 es este:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
    public partial class tabIngresar : Form
    {
        public tabIngresar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        tabRegistro frm2 = new tabRegistro();

        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textUser.Clear();
            picUsuario.Image = Properties.Resources.User2;
            panelUser.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);
            textUser.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);

            picPass.Image = Properties.Resources.Pass1;
            panelPass.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textPass.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        }

        private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textPass.Clear();
            textPass.PasswordChar = '•';
            picPass.Image = Properties.Resources.Pass2;
            panelPass.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);
            textPass.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);

            picUsuario.Image = Properties.Resources.User1;
            panelUser.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textUser.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

          }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
        //Animación
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm2.Left += 10;
            if(frm2.Left >= 830)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                this.TopMost = false;
                frm2.TopMost = true;
                timer2.Start();
            }
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm2.Left -= 10;
            if(frm2.Left <= 525)
            {
                timer2.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Intente hacerlo de la misma forma en el form2 pero me da este error: system.stackoverflowexception

El codigo del form 2 es este:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class tabRegistro : Form
    {
        public tabRegistro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        tabIngresar frm1 = new tabIngresar();
        private void textUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textUser.Clear();
            picUsuario.Image = Properties.Resources.User2;
            panelUser.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);
            textUser.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);

            picPass.Image = Properties.Resources.Pass1;
            panelPass.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textPass.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

            picEmail.Image = Properties.Resources.Email1;
            panelEmail.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textEmail.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        }

        private void textPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textPass.Clear();
            textPass.PasswordChar = '•';
            picPass.Image = Properties.Resources.Pass2;
            panelPass.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);
            textPass.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);

            picUsuario.Image = Properties.Resources.User1;
            panelUser.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textUser.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

            picEmail.Image = Properties.Resources.Email1;
            panelEmail.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textEmail.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        }

        private void textEmail_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textEmail.Clear();
            picEmail.Image = Properties.Resources.Email2;
            panelEmail.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);
            textEmail.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(78, 184, 206);

            picPass.Image = Properties.Resources.Pass1;
            panelPass.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textPass.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

            picUsuario.Image = Properties.Resources.User1;
            panelUser.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            textUser.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm1.Left += 10;
            if (frm1.Left >= 830)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                this.TopMost = false;
                frm1.TopMost = true;
                timer2.Start();
            }
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm1.Left -= 10;
            if (frm1.Left <= 525)
            {
                timer2.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alguien me ayuda? soy nuevo en esto xd...

Mucha Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Tu pregunta esta bien estructurada. Podrias mirar [ask] solo como referencia.. Lo unico raro que veo en tu codigo es esto: tabIngresar frm1 = new tabIngresar(); ya que tu form 2 no esta volviendo al form que lo llamo, si no que esta trayendo un form nuevo, y eso provoca que haya un nuevo form 2 y asi eternamente.

Comment: Hmmm... Vale, entonces como haría para volver al form1?

Comment: mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183312/324) que di en otra pregunta similar. Si no te sirve, trato de explicarte todo de vuelta

Comment: Vale, ya le presente al form2 el form1, pero ahora me aparece este error System.NullReferenceException al intentar volver al form1 (Disculpe mi ignorancia en esto :'v)

Comment: Para eso, existe esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/324