# como puedo mantener datos en un datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, poo, visual-studio-2015, datagrid

[image]

este codigo uso para añadir datos al dgv

```
private void btnAñadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataGridViewRow fila = new DataGridViewRow();
        fila.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
        fila.Cells[0].Value = lblEmpleado.Text;
        fila.Cells[1].Value = lblCi.Text;
        fila.Cells[2].Value = lblCargo.Text;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fila);
    }
```

intento añadir datos al datagrid, pero sin el problema de al llamar otro formulario, los datos previamente introducidos me sobrescriban

Comment: a que te refieres al decir que se te "borran"??, explica de mejor forma tu problema, ademas te recomiendo agregar codigo para que tu pregunta no sea cerrada.

Comment: cuando dices "no necesito una bd" es pregunta? o estas informando que no usas una db

Comment: en que medio conservas los datos que vas agregando? en alguna lista en memoria, en algun archivo, etc

Comment: @Shassain  ahora lo edito, y si me referia a que agrego normal al datagrid pero a ir a otro formulario se queda vacio

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si es estoy informando que no uso una base de datos, no quiero guardar la informacion en ningun archivo solo cuando esta en ejecucion

Comment: Y ese codigo obviamente añade nuevas filas a la grilla. Ahora, a que te referis cuando te vas a otro formulario? que haces con este formulario cuando te vas a otro?

Comment: @gbianchi tengo en otro datagrid, datos almacenados por una lista y rellena los texbox de este, el problema es q al abrir y añadir se van sobrescribiendo y no quisiera que se pierdan esos datos

Comment: No te estaria entendiendo.. podes agregar algun ejemplo de lo que te esta pasando. No me queda claro donde llenas los datos y donde es que se pierden

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no esta en que se pierden los datos del grid cuando visualizas otro formulario, el problema se presenta porque seguramente cuando quieres volver al form anterior creas una nueva instancia usando el `new` en lugar de seguir accediendo a la instancia existente.

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

en el articulo explico sobre el tema.

Pero basicamente cuando cierras el form hijo deberias acceder al form padre que tenias y no a una nueva instancia.

Un ejemplo, en el form hijo

```
public class Form2 : Form{

    private IForm formPadre = null;

    public Form2(){
      InitializeConponent();
    }

    public Form2(IForm frm) : this() {
       this.formPadre = frm;
    }

    public vois button1_click(...){
       this.formPadre.setDato(textbox1.Text);
    }
}
```

en el form padre

```
interface IForm{
   void setDato(string valor);
}

public class Form1 : Form, IForm {

   private string dato;

   public void buton1_click(){
       Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
       frm2.Show();
    }

    public setDato(string valor){
       dato = valor;
    }
}
```

de esta forma puedes pasar datos desde el form de busqueda al form padre que ya tenias instanciado y asi conservar los datos

Veras que el form hijo recibe la instancia del form padre en el constructor, el cual se desacopla usand una interfaz

Comment: Si ese fuera el caso (que OP no termino de aclarar) entonces es una pregunta duplicada de esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/183308/324

Comment: @gbianchi es que no creo que obtengas esa aclaracion porque por lo que explica esta convencido que el problema es como conservar los datos del grid, cuando en realidad estos se conservan, solo que al retornar de un form al otro vuelve a una instancia nueva del form padre en lugar de seguir usando a existente que mantiene los datos. La respuesta del link que porporcionas no convence mucho, le propone definir una variable publica para pasar la instancia del forma padre, pero eso no soluciona la comunicacion entre los forms

Comment: Entonces, si op no hace esa aclaracion, tu respuesta no tiene sentido porque nadie va a buscar comunicacion entre formularios en una pregunta que dice que un dgv no guarda los datos ;). O editamos toda la pregunta y suponemos que esta preguntando (sobre todo el titulo) o esperamos pacientemente que op aclare su problema. Y si no lo aclara la cerramos como no esta claro que se pregunta. Respecto de la otra pregunta, si te parece que se puede mejorar adelante! Pero se centra mas en explicar la teoria de que son objetos, mas qie la comunicacion entre si

Comment: Mi respuesta apunta a guiar a @cristian-soria, no a que se genere la pregunta perfecta, no piento en quien mas va a buscarla porque quizas eso no suceda nunca, la idea es ayudar ahora, no en el futuro a posibles personas que busquen lo mismo. Si la respuesta que doy ayuda despues se puede editar el titulo, pero es una consecuencia no el objetivo que se busca cuando se ayuda. Pero yo tengo muy claro lo que pregunta, por eso brinde una respuesta.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini gracias por entender la consulta, era exactamente lo que preguntaba, en seguida pongo en practica tu ejemplo y

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa por no poner un titulo mas entendible igualmente gracias

Comment: @CristhianCoria no necesitas pedir disculpas. Leiste el [tour]? si esta respuesta te sirivio, aceptala. Pero ten en cuenta para futuras en explicar bien tu problema y hacer un seguimiento de todos los comentarios que se te hacen. Son para que todos entendamos tu problema y podamos darte una respuesta acertada sin adivinar. Aca Leandro adivino, pero podia ser cualquier cosa, porque no explicabas lo que hacias y donde perdias los datos.