# ¿Como cliquear en una fila de un datagrid mediante codigo c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un sistema desktop, en el formulario principal tengo un **datagrid** al seleccionar una de sus filas se me dispara el evento **CellClick** el cual habilita varios **checkbox** al marcar uno de ellos me desplazo hacia otro formulario, el problema radica que al regresar del segundo formulario al primero necesito que se me quede marcado (es decir que se me dispare el evento **CellClick** de la fila que deje seleccionada) para poder seguir llenando los datos y no tener que buscar nuevamente esa fila. He buscado en internet y lo que encontre fue esto pero no me funciona:

```
private void GestionarHuella_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.personalTableAdapter.Fill(this.grehu_etiDataSet.personal);
        if (flag)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid_personas.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt64(grid_personas.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) == idPersona)
                {
                    grid_personas.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    grid_personas_CellClick(grid_personas, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0,i));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Asi accedo al segundo formulario:

```
if (cbox_D0.Checked)
        {
            dedo = 0;
            AddHuella addHuella = new AddHuella(marcas,dedo, idPersona, numTargeta);
            addHuella.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al seleccionar una fila del datagrid me salen los checkbox, al seleccionar un checkbox paso para el segundo formulario.
Asi regreso al primer formulario:

```
gestionarHuella = new GestionarHuella(flag, idPersona);
        gestionarHuella.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar el boton Atras regreso al primer formulario y me debe cargar la fila que seleccione con los checkbox al lado.
Espero entiendan y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ese codigo deberia funcionar.. porque decis que no funciona?

Comment: porque me ejecuta el evento en la primera fila y el valor de `i` es diferente de 0

Comment: deberias agregar entonces tambien que hace cellclick. Tal vez el error esta ahi

Comment: igual a cellclick lo llamas una sola vez.. vos lo queres llamar cuantas veces? quien lo llamaria a la vuelta? y como? este codigo no lo llama, porque una vez que encuentra una fila, es como que selecciona y se termina...

Comment: @gbianchi cellclick lo llamo la cantidad de veces que uno quiera, el load del formulario al que regresa es el que lo llama.

Comment: Entonces muestra el load tambien.. pero el load se ejecuta solo si cargas de nuevo el formulario.. vos lo descargas y volves a cargar? porque simplemente no muestras el otro como modal? sin todo eso, no podriamos decirte donde esta el problema...

Comment: ya lo mostré completo pero era el que habia mostrado

Comment: Ah ok.. tenemos el load.. y que hace el CellClick? porque el load solo se ejecuta al cargar el componente, no cada vez que se muestra...

Comment: haber el CellClick lo que debe hacer es activarse en la fila del datagrid que seleccione en el formulario anterior para que ya me salgan las opciones que deben salir cuando hago click manualmente en una fila. Entiedes...

Comment: yo lo entiendo perfectamente.. no veo el codigo.. y no veo como llamas al otro formulario...

Comment: Eso justamente es lo que debe ir en la pregunta. Y eso es justamente el problema.. Load no se vuelve a ejecutar.. y nadie vuelve a llamar a cellclick...

Comment: Yo quiero que se ejecute el CellClick al regresar del segundo formulario al primero, por esa razon lo pongo en el load del primer fomrulario.

Comment: Y el load solo se ejecuta cuando haces el new del form.. Porfa, agrega eso a la pregunta, borremos todos los comentarios, y armamos una respuesta. Aparte, aclara si los botones que queres ejecutar estan en la misma fila o en distintas

Answer (score 1):

aca hay dos problemas.

Primero, el evento load se ejecuta solamente cuando haces el new del formulario.

Sin embargo, estas teniendo el problema de que no volves al mismo formulario del que partiste.. volves a uno nuevo.

Ese problema ya esta [descripto aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183312/324). Tene en cuenta que estas levantando formularios uno atras de otro. Tu programa tiene montones de formularios vivos.

El segundo problema.. es usar el load...

En realidad, el metodo que llama al fomulario hijo, deberia llamarlo haciendo showmodal. De esa forma, el formulario padre todavia esta vivo.

El metodo que llama a los formularios hijos deberia ser un boton, o estar en el evento Activa del formulario padre. Lo que mas te convenga. Y ahi si, cuando arregles eso, va a funcionar como queres.

Tu codigo esta bien, es ese que tenes ahi, pero solo que tenes que arreglar esos problemas de logica.