# Actualizar Variables de una Clase C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clase, class

Lo que quiero realizar es lo siguiente. 
En una clase llamada "Variables" quiero **almacenar**  la variable String mail = "miMail". De tal manera que al reiniciar mi aplicacion cargue el ultimo valor
asignado en la aplicacion.
En un form quiero utilizar la variable "mail" de mi clase "Variables". 
Para leer mi variable uso el siguiente código que funciona perfecto.

```
      Variables var = new Variables();
        textBox1.Text = var.mail;
```

En el TextBox1 se muestra el valor de la variable "mail".
Ahora lo que quiero hacer es modificar para siempre el valor de la variable mail mediante un formulario. 
Se me ocurrió hacer lo siguiente, pero esto no  actualiza la clase.

```
        Variables var = new Variables();
        var.mail = "nuevo Mail";
```

Comment: Si lo actualiza. Lo que pasa es que tenes que diferencia clase de instancia de clase, que son dos cosas totalmente diferentes. Actualiza la instancia de esa clase. La clase como esta escrita, no se puede modificar. Si sus valores y persistirlos de ser necesario. O pasar esa instancia de clase de un lado para otro.

Comment: Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183312/324) habla sobre formularios, pero bascicamente es el mismo problema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se actualiza la clase porque estas creando instancias distintas de la clase `Variables` si quieres compartirla lo mas simple es difinirla como static, o en caso contrario implementar el patron `singleton`

Para usar `static` seria

```
public static class Variables
{
   public static string mail = "miMail";
}
```

entonces lo usas directo

```
 textBox1.Text = Variables.mail;
```

veras que no hace falta crear una instancia, lo usas directo con el nombre de la clase

Para asignar el valor

```
 Variables.mail = "nuevo Mail";
```

entonces se comparte en toda la aplicacion

[Clases estáticas y sus miembros (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Comment: Es exactamente lo que busco, solo que al detener la aplicación el mail vuelve al definido en un principio, es decir "miMail" y no "nuevo Mail".Quisiera que "nuevo Mail" sea el que quede.

Comment: ehh si claro, poner un valor en una variable no quiere decir que se persista, para eso deberias grabar el valor en el app.config, en un archivo o serializar la clase a xml o json

Comment: Buscaré información por ese lado. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La solución es almacenar la variable "mail" en el app.Config. 
Para ello nos dirigimos a Settings.Settings ubicado en el directorio de nuestro proyecto.
Una vez allí definimos nuestro String.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para recuperar la información guardada en la variable mail utilizariamos el siguiente código:

```
 textBox1.Text= Properties.Settings.Default.mail.ToString();
```

Para almacenar un nuevo valor en la variable utilizaríamos el siguiente código en un botón:

```
 Properties.Settings.Default["mail"] = textBox1.Text;
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```