# ¿Como guardar datos a un DataGridView sin que se borren?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Amablemente solicito de su colaboración para guardar datos desde un textbox a un datagridview sin que al cerrar el formulario la información desaparezca, tener encuenta que no se tiene BD.

Este es el código del botón el cual me envía los datos pero al momento de cerrar el formulario 2 los datos desaparecen:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
   {  
        Form2 hh = new Form2();
        hh.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
        hh.ShowDialog();
    }
```

[image: Formulario 1, textbox donde se escribe el dato y se envía al datagridview.]

[image: Formulario 2, donde quiero que se guarden los datos enviados]

Quedo atento, muchas gracias.

---

Intente pero me genera un error, tu sabrás a que se debe?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aunque no uses una db, tenes que usar algun tipo de "db" aunque sea en memoria. o sea, los datos los deberias guardar en algun lado.. asi sea en la misma grilla ;). Y si no cerras el form, y solo lo ocultas y lo volves a llamar cuando lo necesites?

Comment: Tenes que pasarle una lista al crear form2

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una clase que contenga los valores del grid para guardarlos en forma temporal:

```
public Producto(string s)
{
 this.descripcion= s;
}
```

antes de pasar a tu form donde esta el grid le agregas esto para crear una lista de los items:

```
List<Producto> miLista = null;
```

Agregas el código al botón de guardado:

```
Producto oProducto = new Producto(textbox1.text);

miLista.Add(oProducto);
```

Luego en caso de que quieras usarlo de nuevo en el grid recorres la lista para poder agregar de nuevo los datos al grid.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Lucas no entendi muy bien los pasos a seguir o efectivamente no me resulta.

Comment: @ArturoArnedo debes de crear la clase y la lista en el Form1, para que asi cuando guardes los datos del Grid  del Form2 en la lista se agreguen sin problemas y luego cuando cierres el Form2 los datos persistan en la lista.

Answer (score 1):

tenes dos formas de encarar esto.

O no cerras nunca el form2 de la siguiente forma:

defines a nivel de clase lo siguiente:

```
Form2 formularioSecundario = new Form2(); //Usa nombres de variables que sirvan!
```

y luego en tu botón

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{  
    formularioSecundario.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Clear();
    formularioSecundario.ShowDialog();
}
```

De esta forma, el formulario secundario se queda en memoria aunque no lo veas y mantiene sus datos (un formulario es lo mismo que una clase, mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183312/324))

Otra forma, seria ir guardando los datos en una lista, y luego pasarle esa lista al form2 (yo prefiero no sobrescribir el metodo load del form)

A nivel de clase definis:

```
List<string> ListaDeDatos = new List<string>(); //esta lista es nuestra "base de datos"
```

Y en el boton, haces lo siguiente:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{  
    ListaDeDatos.add(textBox1.Text) //meto el dato en la lista
    Form2 formularioSecundario = new Form2();
    formularioSecundario.CargarDatos(ListaDeDatos); //llamo a una funcion en el otro form
    textBox1.Clear();
    formularioSecundario.ShowDialog();
}
```

Y en el otro formulario escribis una funcion asi:

```
Public void CargarDatos(List<string> ListaRecibida)
{
    foreach(var item in ListaRecibida)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No se puede. Cuando el formulario 2 se cierra, se liberan todos los recursos y la instancia del formulario 2 deja de existir. La única forma es guardando lo que necesitas en un archivo o en una variable global, o en una base de datos.

Creo que la única salida que tienes es ir guardar los valores que vas a enviar en una lista en el formulario 1 y luego enviarlas por medio de parámetro al constructor  del formulario 2 y ahí llenar el datagrid

**FORMULARIO 1**

```
private readonly List<string> lista = new List<string>();

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lista.Add(textBox1.Text);
        Form2 hh = new Form2(lista);
        hh.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**FORMULARIO 2**

```
    public Form2(List<string> lista)
    {
        foreach (var item in lista)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Julio compartí la imagen del error que me genera

Comment: Esto es erroneo, si se puede si no se cierra el formulario (solo se esconde). Los datos se pueden guardar tranquilamente en una lista en memoria (y no tiene por que ser global)

Comment: @gbianchi si lo escondes si funciona, pero si lo cierras se pierde todo. En cuanto a tu segunda solución que planteas es la misma que ya le había planteado, la cual es más funcional que poner invisible el formulario.

Comment: @ArturoArnedo te falta definir la variable de la lista para guardar los elementos que vas agregando. private readonly List<string> lista = new List<string>();