# ¿Por qué mi método no actualiza mi datagridview con mi base sqlite?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms, sqlite

Apenas estoy comenzando en este mundo de las aplicaciones de escritorio para Windows y estoy creando un programa que administre el inventario de laboratorio de una escuela con la base de datos de sqlite y mi problema es el siguiente:

Mi código no actualiza mi **datagridview** desde mi método Cardat() que es el que actualiza los datos.

Estoy utilizando el paquete de nuget System.Data.SQLite.

Desde este formulario mando a llamar al método de otro formulario para que guarde una consulta y en el otro formulario la ejecuta.

```c
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ChemIn_1._0._0
{
    public partial class NW_React : Form
    {
        ///permite aceptar métodos de otro formulario
        private static Reactivos formurec = new Reactivos();

        public NW_React()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ///Verifica que los campos no se encuentren en blanco y guarda los valores de los textbox y los une en una query
        private void Btn_Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                        int Piezas = 0;
                        string NA = Combo_Anaquel.GetItemText(Combo_Anaquel.SelectedItem);
                        string QS = "insert into Reactivos (Clave,Reactivo,Anaquel,Grupo,Piezas)values('"+Txt_Clave.Text+"','"+Txt_Reactivo.Text+"','"+NA+"','"+Txt_Grupo.Text+"','"+Piezas+"')";
                        formurec.SDB(QS);
                        this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí está el formulario que contiene el método al que mando a llamar desde el otro formulario, ejecuto la consulta desde el método SDB y no ejecuta el método Cardat.

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace ChemIn_1._0._0
{
    public partial class Reactivos : Form
    { 
        private SQLiteConnection sqlconec;
        private SQLiteCommand comma;
        private SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
        private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        public Reactivos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Cardat();
        }

        ///Guardar datos a la base de datos
        public void SDB(String Cmd_Guar)
        {
            EjQuery(Cmd_Guar);
            Cardat();
        }

        ///Iniciar conexión
        private void ConectarSql()
        {
            sqlconec = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ChemIn.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
        }

        /// Ejecutar querys
        private void EjQuery(string TXQuery)
        {
            ConectarSql();
            sqlconec.Open();
            comma = sqlconec.CreateCommand();
            comma.CommandText = TXQuery;
            comma.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconec.Close();
        }

        /// Cargar datos al datagridview
        public void Cardat()
        {
            ConectarSql();
            sqlconec.Open();
            comma = sqlconec.CreateCommand();
            string Comandodetx = "select * from Reactivos";
            DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Comandodetx, sqlconec);
            DS.Reset();
            DB.Fill(DS);
            DT = DS.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
            sqlconec.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Me guié de este video para hacer mi código:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83XnLXRwmbU&t=376s

Comment: Como es que mostras el otro formulario, si nunca tenes un show en tu codigo?

Comment: tengo un formulario padre en el cual coloco formularios hijos que los voy cambiando por medio de botones.

Comment: algo asi: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7I0b2DsqkD8.

Comment: Perfecto.. pero ese formulario al cual le estas pasando la query, es el mismo que el padre?

Comment: Nop, es un formulario hijo.

Comment: me parece que tu problema es este: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/183308/324

Comment: y el formulario que crea la query, es un un formulario normal.