# como hacer botón home o back en windows-form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy tratando de hacer un botón estilo home o back, es decir que al presionar me regrese al formulario principal, pero el método que estoy utilizando me abre varios formularios, como evito eso.

Este es el botón que digo que necesito al presionar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente estoy utilizando este.

FrmPrincipal frmp = new FrmPrincipal();
        frmp.Show();

pero lo que hace es que me envía adelante el formulario, aquí la imagen de lo que hace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También trate de utilizar este código de revisión, pero no me hace nada.

Form frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast().FirstOrDefault(x => x is FrmPrincipal);

```
    if (frm != null)
    {
        //si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
        frm.BringToFront();
        return;
    }

    //sino existe la instancia se crea una nueva
    frm = new FrmPrincipal();
    frm.Show();
```

Gracias y espero sus sugerencias.

Comment: Tu imagen no demuestra el problema... vos no queres abrir uno nuevo, si no volver atras en tu mismo form???

Comment: si, lo que pasa es que tengo un formulario central en el cual tengo los modulos, y cuando accedo a uno va bien, ahora cuando le doy al icono home/inicio, me abre el formulario principal, pero me deja el otro abierto, como esta en la imagen de arriba.

Comment: Si pero no se entiende bien a donde deberias volver... (mismo form? Otro form y cerrar ese? Otro control?)

Comment: si ves bien la imagen en donde están los dos formularios, deseo volver siempre al que tiene los 8 botones, es decir el de la derecha, que cuando este en cualquier otra ventana presione el botón home y me lleve ahí sin necesidad de que se abran mas formularios. es igual como en las paginas web, eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: Si perfecto. Pero no decis como es tu navegacion... controles? Formularios? O sea tu codigo esta bien, si tu navegacion fuera por formularios.

Comment: es por formularios, mira hacia donde quiero llevar cuando presione,  https://ibb.co/Gx1Vgqz

Comment: Y entonces tu codigo funciona.. lo unico que no estas haciendo es cerrar el form actual... a ver si esta pregunta te ayuda... https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183312/324

Comment: Si tu aplicacion comienza con Form1 cuanto entra en el main. Solo con cerrar los otros ya lo verias, o cambias desde la barra de windows al formulario existente.

Comment: Por qué no utilizas paneles desde el mismo formulario? Y los vas activando desactivando con la propiedad visible

Answer (score 0):

Al escribir `frm = new frmPincipal`, estás creando realmente un nuevo formulario, si lo que quieres es volver al anterior, simplemente cierra el formulario actual.

Es decir, al abrir la segunda ventana desde frmPrincipal haz algo como esto:

```
frmSecondary frm = new frmSecondary();

  frm.ShowDialog();
```

`ShowDialog` muestra el formulario secundario y espera hasta que este formulario se cierre.

Para cerrar este segundo formulario, en el manejador del evento del botón Home, escribe ésto:

```
   this.Close();
```