# Como usar una clase no estatica dentro de una que es estatica

Tags: c#, wpf, static

Tengo un DataGrid en MainWindow.xaml llamado "DG_Scanner", necesito poder enviarle datos desde un metodo estatico llamado "printService" que esta en MainWindow.xaml.cs, no me permite comunicarme con el exterior porque es estatico.

Codigo del MainWindow:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string serviceType = "_http._tcp";

        ServiceBrowser serviceBrowser = new ServiceBrowser();
        serviceBrowser.ServiceAdded += onServiceAdded;
        serviceBrowser.ServiceRemoved += onServiceRemoved;
        serviceBrowser.ServiceChanged += onServiceChanged;
        serviceBrowser.StartBrowse(serviceType);
    }
    
    static void onServiceChanged( object sender, ServiceAnnouncementEventArgs e)
    {
        printService(null ,'~', e.Announcement);
    }

    static void onServiceRemoved(object sender, ServiceAnnouncementEventArgs e)
    {
        printService(null ,'-', e.Announcement);
    }

    static void onServiceAdded( object sender, ServiceAnnouncementEventArgs e)
    {
        printService(null ,'+', e.Announcement);
    }

    static void printService(MainWindow window,char startChar, ServiceAnnouncement service)
    {
        y = new List<Data>();
        y.Add(new Data() { hostname = service.Hostname });
        y.Add(new Data() { maccaddress = " " });
        y.Add(new Data() { name = " " });
        y.Add(new Data() { port = " " });
        window.DG_scanner.Items.Add(y);
    }
```

La lista se envia a un DataGrid, esos datos deben mostrarse en el MainWindow.xaml cuando se ejecute

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Le falta contexto, pero si haces una nueva mainwindow, no estas accediendo a la que ya esta, estas accediendo a una nueva... y eso es lo que queres?? o esa ventana (que es una clase como cualquier otra) ya tiene una instancia y queres ir a esa?

Comment: Ya tiene una instancia y quiero ir a esa

Comment: A que te refieres con que se queda cargando? Que hace exactamente?

Comment: Aparece la ventana en blanco(deberia aparecer el DataGrid) y no me permite hacer nada el cursor se pone en espera dando vueltas.

Comment: Entonces vas a necesitar ir a esa instancia.. No a una nueva (new -> nueva instancia, las ventanas son objetos como cualquier otro). Tenes que pasarsela al metodo, obtenerla de algun lado, o hacer algo para saber cual es la instancia.. esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183312/324) te va a servir para entender tu problema

Comment: No me funciona, solo quiero poder enviarle data al  DataGrid que esta en MainWindows.xaml desde un metodo estatico que esta en MainWindows.xaml.cs

Comment: Que cosa no te funciona? que metodo estatico esta llamando a este? como es la cadena de llamadas? porque ese metodo no pasa la instacia de la ventana que estas usando?

Comment: Porque este metodo es estatico? esta en la misma clase que la ventana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deebrias definir

```
static void printService(MainWindow window, char startChar, ServiceAnnouncement service)
{
    var y = new List<Data>();
    y.Add(new Data() { hostname = service.Hostname });
    y.Add(new Data() { maccaddress = " " });
    y.Add(new Data() { name = " " });
    y.Add(new Data() { port = " " });

    window.DG_scanner.Items.Add(y);

}
```

entonces desde la ventana pasas la instancia de esa ventana, si esto lo invocas desde `MainWindow` usarias

```
printService(this, varStart, varService);
```

Al usar el `this` desde `MainWindow` haces referencia a la instancia de esa ventana

Nota: puse los "varXX" porque no se que valor le asignas

Comment: Fijate que OP esta mas confundido de lo que parece.. si el metodo esta dentro de la misma clase ventana, no entiendo el problema que tiene... La solucion esta es correcta si el metodo esta en otra clase

Comment: No puedo, ya que los metodos que llaman a "printService" son estaticos tambien

Comment: entonces vas a tener que pasarle a esos otros metodos tambien la instancia de MainWindow

Comment: lo que no entiendo es porque necesitas que esos metodos sean static, que pasa si le quitas el static? en que contexto estan esos metodo? estan dentro de la class de MainWindows.xaml.cs ?

Comment: Antes me lanzaba un error cuando los dejaba solo "void", pero ahora se los quite y todo funciona como quiero

Comment: Gracias, ese era el problema, no sé por que circunstancia no me dejaba hacerlo antes.