# Como utilizar variables de una ventana de wpf en otra?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

estoy programando una tienda ficticia que tiene un carro de compra, cada producto tiene un checkbox para marcar lo que el usuario quiere comprar.
[image: ventana de la tienda]

cuando se marca un checkbox, una variable booleana se transforma en true.

lo que quiero hacer es que al ir a la ventana de carro se muestre en una listview todas los productos seleccionados, pero para hacer eso necesito pasar la informacion de las variables a la otra ventana.

[image: ventana del carro]

alguien sabría como hacerlo? muchas gracias.
PD: este programa se esta haciendo en c# WPF Visual Studio

Comment: Hay tantas formas de hacer esto, que no se por donde empezar.. para empezar, sabias que los forms son clases no? y que cuando lo instancias, le podes compartir valores como a cualquier otra clase no? y que dos forms podrian apuntar a otra clase para compartir la informacion que tiene la misma? que sean forms, no implica que no sean clases comunes y corrientes como las otras.. solo que estas, se saben dibujar.. mira aca por ejemplohttps://es.stackoverflow.com/q/183308/324

Comment: Como dicen, hay mil formas, si tienes los productos en una lista, pasa la lista por parámetro y accedes a sus propiedades, puedes pasar la ventana completa como parámetro a otra ventana con el THIS, puedes enviar la lista ya filtrada previamente con una simple consulta LINQ que elimine de la lista los productos que no estén seleccionado, yo creo que esa es la mejor forma, var seleccionados = lista.Where(x => x.IsSelected = true).ToList<MiProducto>(); y ese VAR lo pasas a tu nueva form.

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de pasar un objeto de una ventana a otra o de un control de usuario a otro, la mas simple es crear un clase de parámetros estáticos y pasar los parámetros por medio de propiedades. Algo asi:

```
public static ParametrosEstaticos
{
   public static List<Producto> ProductoSeleccionado { get; set; }
}
```

Y al ejecutar el evento del botón ir al carro simplemente hacer esto:

```
ParametrosEstaticos.ProductoSeleccionado.Add(ItemSeleccionado);
```